# How to read datetime in local timezone

Tags: go, mongo-go

I use github.com/mongodb/mongo-go-driver driver in golang
My code struct:

```
type Document struct {
   CreatedAt time.Time `bson:"createdAt"`
}
```

When I insert a document, it is inserted as ISODate (), it looks like this:

```
{
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2019-06-12T08:55:45Z")
}
```

From the code, when I receive the document, he read in the UTC time zone.
I want to convert the date in my local Timezone system. Is there any way to do this with the driver

Comment: That 'Z' at the end of your date literally means "this us UTC, not local time"

Comment: Use mongodb stored datetime in UTC, without timezone. But driver can transform datetime to my local timezone. MGO driver can this